# webdriver.get() raise TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i use selenium in combination with celery and mitmproxy to scan cookies from several websites every day.
Yesterday my application crashes in consequence of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myapplication/myapplication/api/tasks.py", line 24, in scan_periodically
    x.startscanner(executor=Scan.PERIODICALLY)
  File "/home/myapplication/myapplication/api/scanner.py", line 204, in startscanner
    self.browser_list[self.browser_list_place].get(self.website.url)
  File "/home/myapplication/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/myapplication/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/myapplication/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=76.0.3809.100)
```

I use the python api from selenium with python version 3.7.3, selenium api version 3.141.0 and Google Chrome 76.0.3809.100 with chromedriver version 76.0.3809.68.

Why the webdriver get() method raises a TimeoutException?

Comment: Is your url valid??

Comment: Yes, it's a valid url.

Comment: Can you post it to check it? Also try my answer with timeouts

Comment: What does `get(self.website.url)` resembles to?

Comment: @Wonka no sorry, the url is secret.

Comment: @DebanjanB to a url like `https://example.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this arguments for avoid/override timeout, I found them on my selenium library

```
import socket
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

#Init your browser, then
#...

socket.setdefaulttimeout(int(60))

your_browser_driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
```

Comment: Why do you need `import socket` :)

Comment: @DebanjanB I did it 1 or 2 years ago, I get this exception "socket.timeout" on driver.get() so I assume that selenium is using socket and get that from some stackoverflow solution

Comment: I think thats not help because my exception is different from yours. I can't try your solution because the exception not fire always. The exception fire occasional.